# Can Raphael's line graph library plot inconsistent time series data?

Tags: graph, raphael, javascript

I'm trying to get Raphael's line chart library to draw multiple value sets across the same time series, but where the values in each set aren't consistent (ie. in each set, there isn't always a y value for every x value).

In other words, instead of looking like this:

```
    r.g.linechart(10,10,300,220,[1,2,3,4,5],[[10,20,30,40,50], [20,30,40,50,60], [30,40,50,60,70]]);
```

my data - like much 'real world' data - is imperfect, and looks a bit more like this:

```
    r.g.linechart(10,10,300,220,[1,2,3,4,5],[[10,"",30,40,50], [20,30,"",50,60], [30,40,50,"",70]]);
```

By default, if there are fewer y values in any set (than the total number of x values), the values in the set are assigned to x values in normal sequence. In other words, any 'gaps' are pushed to the end.

Any ideas how to plot my 'holier' data?

Answer (score 1):

i got the same question.
we currently using ExtJs for our charts but there's some bug with time series. 
we checked dygraph, highcharts but for some reasons we are not using it.
and all d3.js stuff is not compatible with IE8.

Raphael seems to be a good alternative and i'm interested to know if it is possible ?